# Generators of finite group keep their orders in a quotient

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given $g_1,\dotsc,g_n \in G$ generate the finite group $G$, and under a surjective homomorphism between finite groups $\phi: G\to H$, the orders of $g_n$ are unchanged (i.e. same as those of $\phi(g_n)$), must it be the case that $\phi$ is an isomorphism? If not, when does this statement fail to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the projection $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ onto the first coordinate.

Comment: The element $(0,1)$ has order two but $\phi(0,1)=0$ has order one, so this doesn't satisfy the OP's conditions.

Comment: Ah ok, if $g_1=(1,0),g_2=(1,1)$ then I guess we're fine. In that case nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample of rather general nature are non-elementary abelian $p$-groups $G$ of exponent $p$. In this case - in contrast to Serkan's example - the epimorphism $G \to G/[G,G]$ onto the abelianization preserves the orders of *each* minimal generation set of $G$.

As an explicit example you can take $G$ to be the group of upper triangular matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $1$'s in the diagonal. It has order $p^3$ and abelianization $\mathbb{Z}/p \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p$.